# Создание массива из TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день, подскажите как можно задать кол-во элементов массива из TextBox?

Должно получится что-то типа:

```
string[] myArr = new string[TextBox.Text];
```

Выдает ошибку что не может преобразовать string в int

Или может быть подскажите другой способ, мне нужно чтобы исходя из числа введенного в TextBox добавлялись записи в ListBox.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно!
Text- это `string`.
Сделайте `int32.Parse(TextBox.Text)` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: По хорошему прежде нужно проверять пользовательский ввод, поэтому лучше будет использовать `TryParse`

Comment: @Bulson, это да, но возможно, у него в TextBox'e стоит ограничение на ввод символов и эта проверка будет излишней.

Comment: У того кто задал такой вопрос... будет стоять ограничение..., не смешите меня.

Answer (score 2):

Свойство `Text` элемента [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) Возвращает или задает текстовое содержимое текстового поля (**string**).

Для создания массива заданной длины необходимо воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
type[] array = new type[N];
```

где

- type - тип переменных содержащихся в массиве. Элементы массива могут
  быть любых типов, включая тип массива;
- N - число элементов массива. Должно быть представлено целым положительным числом, включая 0. Таблицу целых типов, можно посмотреть на сайте [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/exx3b86w.aspx)

В конкретно этом случае вы передаете тип **string**.

> string[] myArr = new string[TextBox.Text];

Для решения проблемы, необходимо привести содержимое `TextBox.Text` к целочисленному типу. 
Приведу пример преобразования. Данный пример учитывает, что в **TextBox.Text** введены корректные данные.

```
n = int.Parse(TextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный способ для случая, если вы пользуетесь MVVM — привязать `TextBox` к целочисленному свойству.

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int n;
    public int N
    {
        get { return n; }
        set { if (n != value) { n = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    // ...
    void OnUserAction
    {
        string[] myArr = new string[N];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Соответственно в XAML делаете привязку:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding N}" ... />
```

(Разумеется, тут ещё нужны проверки, без них никуда.)